# encoding RGB colors in 16 bits

Tags: colors, bit

I'm reading an android game development book and i've come across the RGB triplet: (31, 31, 45) using 16 bits (Red gets 5 bits, Green gets 6 bits, Blue gets 5 bits).

I'm a little confused on the last number in the triplet: 45. If the last coordinate is for the color blue, and blue only gets 5 bits, how is it possible to have a 45 in the last coordinate spot? Shouldn't the highest number possible for blue be 31?

BTW supposedly this triplet creates the color pink.

can someone help clear up the confusion?

thanks!

Edit: if it helps the hexadecimal for the color is 0xFC0D

Comment: FYI got a similar problem and wrote a [converter in python](https://gist.github.com/bernardpaulus/285e3a6be3e34fc57222b7a144cde684) to do 24 <-> 16 bits

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your hex code shows what happens: 45 = 0x2d, but the hex code only has 0xd in the lower bits, basically the high order bit is chopped off because you are correct the highest possible value is 0x1F.

Probably something that just slipped by testers/editors.

It is likely that the RGB code is built like this:

```
RGB(r,g,b)
{
    code = (r & 0x1f) << 11;
    code |= (g & 0x3f) << 5;
    code |= (b & 0x1f) << 0;
}
```

So any extra bits are just masked off.

Comment: Ok, those kinds of things in books always frustrate me. Thanks though!

Answer (score 0):

FC0D in hex is

1111110000001101 in binary

So

R=b11111=31
G=b100000=32
B=b01101=13